# "Permission denied" in open() function in C

Tags: c, file-access

I am new to C programming. I am having problem writing to a file using the open() function in C, here is my code for clarity

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void usage(char *prog_name, char *filename){
    printf("Usage: %s <data to add to %s> \n",prog_name, filename);
    exit(0);
}

void fatal(char *);                          
void *errchck_malloc(unsigned int);     

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int fd; // File descriptor
    char *buffer, *datafile;

    buffer = (char *) errchck_malloc(100);
    datafile = (char *) errchck_malloc(20);
    strcpy(datafile, "./simplenote.txt");

    if (argc < 2)
        usage(argv[0], datafile);

    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);

    printf("[DEBUG] buffer @ %p: \'%s\'\n", buffer, buffer);
    printf("[DEBUG] datafile @ %p: \'%s\'\n", datafile, datafile);

    strncat(buffer, "\n", 1);

    // Open file 
    fd = open(datafile, O_CREAT|O_RDWR,O_APPEND, S_IRUSR, S_IWUSR);
    if(fd == -1)
        fatal("in main() while opening file");
    printf("[DEBUG] file descriptor is %d\n", fd);

    // Writing data to file
    if(write(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer))==-1)
        fatal("in main() while writing buffer to file");

    // Closing file
    if(close(fd) == -1)
        fatal("in main() while closing file");

    printf("Note saved\n");
    free(buffer);
    free(datafile);
}

// fatal(): Function to display error message then exit
void fatal(char *message){
    char err_msg[100];

    strcpy(err_msg, "[!!] Fatal Error ");
    strncat(err_msg, message, 83);
    perror(err_msg);
    exit(-1);
}

// errchck_malloc(): An error check malloc wrapper function
void *errchck_malloc(unsigned int size){
    void *ptr;
    ptr = malloc(size);
    if(ptr == NULL)
        fatal("in errchck_malloc() on memory allocation");
    return ptr;
}
```

When I execute the program on the first try, the program runs as expected.

first run:

```
user: ./simplenote "Hello, again"
[DEBUG] buffer @ 0x7fafcb4017a0: 'Hello again'
[DEBUG] datafile @ 0x7fafcb401810: './simplenote.txt'
[DEBUG] file descriptor is 3
Note saved
```

when I try to open the file and view the text, I get a permission denied error. when I try to open the file with sudo, it opens and the text is in the file. When I run the program a second time, I get an error while opening the file because of permission issues.

second run:

```
user: ./simplenote "just checking if it is still working"                                                           
[DEBUG] buffer @ 0x7face4c017a0: 'just checking if it is still working'
[DEBUG] datafile @ 0x7face4c01810: './simplenote.txt'
[!!] Fatal Error in main() while opening file: Permission denied
```

**How do I fix the permission issues with the file creation?**

Comment: The arguments of `open()` are not correct. I ran the code and it created a file whose only permission is execute for group. This is the cause of the error on subsequent executions.

Comment: isn't that the code from the book "the art of exploitation" by jon ericson?

Comment: @sf_admin yes it is. thanks

Comment: @Tijani you should write something like here is the code from the book "The art of exploitation", but when I try running it I get the following errors.. instead of "here is my code"

Answer (score 7):

File created when program run for first time has permissions that does not allows you to append

```
stat simplenote.txt 
  File: simplenote.txt
  Size: 5           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 2fh/47d Inode: 32810078    Links: 1
Access: (2000/------S---)  Uid: ( 1000/ user)   Gid: ( 1000/ user)
Access: 2020-01-05 19:29:34.317872734 +0100
Modify: 2020-01-05 19:29:34.317872734 +0100
Change: 2020-01-05 19:29:34.317872734 +0100
```

You should combine mode using `|` like this:

```
fd = open(datafile, O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

You can check what arguments you should pass to `open` using `man open`, on my system it show something like this (trimmed to important parts):

```
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);

   int creat(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);

   int openat(int dirfd, const char *pathname, int flags);
   int openat(int dirfd, const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

Answer (score 3):

The arguments of `open()` are not correct. The [documentation of `open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) says:

> int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);

`O_APPEND` is a flag, it should be OR-ed with the other two to produce the `flags` argument.

`S_IRUSR` and `S_IWUSR` are permissions. They should be OR-ed to produce the `mode` argument.

All in all, the call to `open()` should be:

```
fd = open(datafile, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

Comment: Note that `open()` is a variable argument list function (POSIX [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html)).  It takes 2 or 3 arguments — using the third when the second include `O_CREAT` and the file needs to be created.  The OP's code passes 4 arguments.  This is permitted by the `open(const char *pathname, int flags, ...);` signature (which is why there's no compiler warning about the fourth argument), but the extra arguments are ignored.