# Permission Denied when trying to use open() with POSIX commands in C++

Tags: c++, macos, posix, permission-denied

I currently have this code where I need to use standard POSIX calls to write text to a file:

```
file = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
   if (file == -1) {
        perror("File cannot be opened");
        return -1;
    }
```

However, every time I run it, I get the permission denied error:
`File cannot be opened: Permission denied`

I tried finding something online and found this ["Permission denied" in open() function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59602852/permission-denied-in-open-function-in-c)
but when trying those suggestions, I get the same issue and idk if it's because I am using C++ while they were using C. For reference, I am on a Mac and am running this through an IDE (CLion)

please help!

Comment: What file are you trying to open? This is a permissions issue. Either set the file permissions or run the application with root permissions: `$ sudo myapp`

Comment: Where are you trying to create the file? In what directory? Do your user have rights to write to that directory? What user is the owner of the directory? What protection flags are set on that directory?